# How does make automatically create .o file

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have a file hello.c (no hello.o yet).
When I give command

```
gcc -o hello hello.o
```

It gives error `gcc: error: hello.o: No such file or directory`, but when I create a makefile containing following rule,

```
hello: hello.o
    gcc -o hello hello.o
```

and run `make`, it automatically creates `hello.o` from `hello.c` and then successfully creates `hello` executable.
Since I didn't write command to create hello.o from hello.c in makefile, how does make know which command it should run?

Comment: Gnu make has a few [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make` has not only uses the rules you added explicitly in makefiles, it has implicit rules as well. The full list you can find at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules
and the first implicit rule in the list is

> Compiling C programs
>
> n.o is made automatically from n.c with a recipe of the form ‘$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c’.

Answer (score 0):

Because make has been around the block enough to have [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) about how to transform a .c file to a .o file:

> Compiling C programs
>
> ```
> n.o is made automatically from n.c with a recipe of the form
> ‘$(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c’.
> ```